# Exporting a CSV adjusting a category with ToTitleCase

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

```
#First Name
$GivenName = Import-Csv .\Documents\db1.csv | select GivenName 

$UserF = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($GivenName) 

$UserF | Export-Csv .\Documents\UsersF.txt –NoTypeInformation
```

When I run the script I get a .txt file with

```
#TYPE System.String
"Length"
"98"
```

What I want is the FirstName category with the proper Title Case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be simpler than expected. Just update you existing `$GivenName` like this:

```
$GivenName|%{$_.givenname = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_.GivenName)}
```

Then you can do a `$GivenName|Export-CSV .\Documents\UsersF.txt -NoTypeInformation` and there's no need to create a whole other variable for the exact same info.